# Hibernate will not remove item in delete test method in Spring app

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm working on integration testing of a spring application,
and I'm trying to test a simple delete method.

I first add an item (in my case a sector) and then test its deletion.
However, when the test method is run it is called but as if the item is not deleted, I do not know for what reason.

Location and sectors are smaller in relation one to may - many to one,  where location has more sectors.
Currently I have 7 sectors in the test database and it is added to the 8 one, which has id 8 because the id is set to identity.

This is my test method (have @Transactional on test class):

```
 @Test
 public void deleteSectorTest(){
    Sector sector = sectorService.addSector(SectorConst.newDtoToAdd());

    int sizeBeforeDel = sectorRepository.findAll().size();

    sectorService.deleteSector(8L);

    int sizeAfterDel = sectorRepository.findAll().size();

    assertEquals(sizeBeforeDel - 1, sizeAfterDel);
}
```

This is my methods add and delete sector in sector service:

```
public Sector addSector(SectorDto sd) {

    Sector sector = new Sector();

    if(locationService.findOneLocation(sd.getLocationId()) == null){
        throw new LocationNotFoundException("Location with id : " +sd.getLocationId() +" not found.");
    }

    Location l = locationService.findOneLocation(sd.getLocationId());


        sector = mapFromDto(sd);
        sector.setLocation(l);

        l.getSectors().add(sector);

        sectorRepository.save(sector);

    return sector;
}

public void deleteSector(Long id){

    sectorRepository.deleteById(id);
}
```

And here is my error in console: 
[image]

If anyone knows what the problem is I would appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Did you modify your FlushMode anywhere in configs? Also, please add the body of `sectorRepository.deleteById(id)`.

Comment: The method deleteById(id) is built into the repository. And as for FlushMode, I didn't know it needed to be modify at all, and I didn't know how to set it and where.

Comment: What do you mean it's "built into repository"? Could you show how it's implemented? As for the FlushMode - you don't need to modify it, but if you were - this could've explained your problem.

Comment: Check the ID of item being inserted, my guess you're expecting it to be id 8 but it's not. Would need the entities, and DB schema to confirm

Comment: I have debugged multiple times and am pretty sure id is good.